# Expresiones Regulares. Help

Tags: javascript, regex

Recien estoy entrando a esto de expresiones regulares. Y quiero intentar hacer como un buscador de palabras, al mas estilo de whatsapp. Que colocas buscar una palabra o letra y te muestra todas las coincidencias.

La cuestion es la siguiente.

```
let regex1 = new RegExp(/l/gi);
let texto = "Cualquier texto";
let array;
while((array = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null){
let index = regex1.lastIndex;
let oracion = str1.split(' ');

console.log(`Encontramos una coincidencia en ${array[0]}. 
Esta en  ${index} '${oracion[regex1]}'`);
```

Ahi el exec me encuentra la letra l en la oracion y me devuelve el indice de donde se encuentra esa letra. Pero yo quiero que tambien me devuelva la palabra completa.

Ese codigo lo saque de la pagina de ejemplos de DevMoz. Tambien estoy intentando con split y configurando bien la expresion regular con todos los simbolos necesarios pero sigo sin dar en el clavo.

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente utilizando `/\w*l\w*/gi` de la siguiente manera:

```
regex = new RegExp(/\w*l\w*/gi);
texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent iaculis elit mi."
```

Lo cual te arrojaría como resultado lo siguiente:

```
regex.exec(texto)
["Lorem", index: 0, input: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… elit mi. Morbi ut leo maximus, lobortis elit vel", groups: undefined]
regex.exec(texto)
["dolor", index: 12, input: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… elit mi. Morbi ut leo maximus, lobortis elit vel", groups: undefined]
regex.exec(texto)
["elit", index: 51, input: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… elit mi. Morbi ut leo maximus, lobortis elit vel", groups: undefined]
```

Y para recuperar la palabra e índice únicamente tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
palabra = regex.exec(texto)
palabra[0]
// "Lorem"
palabra['index']
// 0
```

`\w` Coincide con cualquier letra, dígito o guión bajo. Equivalente a utilizar `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.